# My js files are empty when running on Win10 Azure VM

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-10, azure-virtual-machine

I started a Win10 Azure VM with VS 2015 and launched my MVC app using IIS. The js scripts appear to resolve; the paths generated by the bundles all appear legit, but the code isn't visible from the F12 dev tools and I get "'$' is undefined" on my first in-page jQuery call, meaning the jQuery reference, among others, didn't resolve. The browser (Edge, IE, ...) has javascript enabled. Is there some Windows settings that's blocking the resolution of these scripts?

#### Edit 1

The bundles load correctly if running in IIS Express. I need this to run in IIS though. In order to get MS Account integration I have to have a hosts entry to spoof my site as a www...com address. I tried to get that to work in IIS Express before and had no luck.

Comment: does it work on other browsers?

Comment: your browsers network tab should tell you whether jQuery/a bundle including jQuery is loaded.

Comment: The page markup has a generated line for the jquery script path that looks correct and the network session shows a 200 success for the jquery file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the pre-packaged installation of IIS didn't have "Static Content" enabled.